# MySQLi prepare statement gives blank responses

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to get the data from table row from information via cookie.

Here's what I have so far:

```
    $cookie_id = @$_COOKIE['id'];
    $cookie_pass = @$_COOKIE['password'];

if ($_COOKIE['id']) {

    if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, "SELECT id, password FROM `members` WHERE id=? AND password=?")) {

        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $cookie_id, $cookie_pass);

        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

        mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $cookie_id, $cookie_pass);

        $logged = mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);
        printf("USER ID: %s\n", $cookie_id);
        // prints "1"

        echo "Hello, " . $logged['username'] . "!";
    }
}
```

And that yields: `USER ID: 1 Hello, !` at the very top of the page.

**What am I doing wrong?** I am trying to get it so I can get the username from the table row I am trying to locate. **How do I get the $logged['username'] (or any data from the row), based on the password and ID, to show up?**

and adding `error_reporting(E_ALL);` does not show any additional errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just selecting `password` and `id` from table so when you are will fetch the data you will not get `username`

The general syntax is

```
SELECT col1,col2, .... coln FROM `members` WHERE id=? AND password=?
```

either you have to use `*` for specify the columns you want to select

your process should be something like this :

```
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, "SELECT id, password , username FROM `members` WHERE id=? AND password=?")) {

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ss", $cookie_id, $cookie_pass);

    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $cookie_id, $cookie_pass, $username);

    printf("Hello %s", $username);

}
```

You can refer [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php)

Comment: @CORRUPT Thanks for pointing out .. I just read question again .. OP is selecting one row so no need

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to print the username field but the select portion of your query is only retrieving the id and password fields. Unlike mysqli_get_result() or similar functions, mysqli_stmt_fetch() only returns a boolean for success or failure, the output is passed to the variables assigned to it in the mysqli_stmt_bind_result() function. Adding $username as a third parameter to that function and adding username to the end of your select query will populate the $username variable with the user's username after the call to fetch().

To clarify, your query should be:

```
SELECT id, password,username FROM `members` WHERE id=? AND password=?
```

and the call to bind should be:

```
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $cookie_id, $cookie_pass, $username);
```

Comment: You forgot to include `username` in select query.. :)

Comment: Thank you, probably should stop coding at 1 AM :p

Comment: Should stop whenever you feel like not getting upto it :)

Comment: How come when I do this ` mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $cookie_id, $cookie_pass, $username, $uid);` I get `Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement `

Comment: @weka This is because you are selecting 3 columns and doing binding for 4